# jQuery Ajax pageload <div> puzzle

Tags: wordpress, jquery, pageload

Still learning this jQuery stuff....

I like this ajax page loader; it works for Wordpress on a `<div id="content">` right out of the box. But one thing bothers me: the  collapses while ajax loads the page and spins the spinner, and I'd like to be able to have the div retain some of it's size instead of making the footer of the page jump up and then down. The  doesn't have to be taller than 500-600 px, just so it doesn't bounce the footer up and down. Is that possible with this function in the way it's written? Below are the most relevant functions. (Others I've left out have to to with Wordpress and its URL structure.)

```
function loadPage(url){
  if(!isWorking){
    scroll(0,0);
    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML='<center><img src="'+loadingIMG.src+'" /></center>';
    http.open('GET',url,true);
    isWorking=true;
    http.onreadystatechange=showPage;
    http.send(null);
  }
}

function showPage(){
  if(http.readyState==4){
    if(http.status==200){
      isWorking=false;
      var content = http.responseText;
      content = content.split('id="content"')[1];
      content = content.substring(content.indexOf('>')+1);
      var depth=1;
      var output='';
      while(depth>0){
        temp = content.split('</div>')[0];
        //count occurrences
        i=0;
        pos = temp.indexOf("<div");
        while(pos!=-1){
          i++;
          pos = temp.indexOf("<div",pos+1);
        }
        //end count
        depth=depth+i-1;
        output=output+content.split('</div>')[0]+'</div>';
        content = content.substring(content.indexOf('</div>')+6);
      }
      document.getElementById('content').innerHTML=output;
      pageLoaderInit();
    }else{
      alert(http.status);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: no jQuery script here is there? please dont misuse the tag. www.jQuery.com for more input on the subject.

Comment: If you read my question, I wrote that I included only the most relevant functions, not all the jQuery overhead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't actually see any jquery there, but you should be able to use plain old javascript to set the height of the content div.

In loadPage:

```
var contentDiv = document.getElementById('content');
contentDiv.innerHTML='<center><img src="'+loadingIMG.src+'" /></center>';
contentDiv.style.height = "600px";
```

In showPage:

```
var contentDiv = document.getElementById('content');
contentDiv.innerHTML=output;
contentDiv.style.height = "";
```

Comment: Thanks, that works great. Now I have to figure out how to keep to keep both permalinks and active page menu highlighting in place while reloading the content; that's for other questions....